# Why does gsynth sometimes fail with "'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL''"?

Tags: r, statistics

Disclaimer: I have minimal experience with R, though am familiar with programming in general. All examples were run in RStudio using version 4.0.2 of R.

I am using a package called [gsynth](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsynth/gsynth.pdf) to conduct an analysis on some political data. I have a data frame named `vdem5` with five variables: `country`, `corruption`, `democracy`, `bnp` and `eu` (eu is dichotomous/binary, indicates eu-membership). I have tried using gsynth in accordance with [their example page](https://yiqingxu.org/software/gsynth/gsynth_examples.html) as such:

```
out <-  gsynth(corruption ~ eu + democracy + bnp, data = vdem5, 
                      index = c("country","year"), force = "two-way",
                      CV = TRUE, r= c(0,5), se = TRUE, 
                      inference = "parametric", nboots = 1000,
                      parallel = FALSE)
```

Console output looks like this:
[image: Console output]

I have checked multiple times that vdem5 is not `NULL` and that all the columns have no missing data (although gsynth supposedly can handle this).

What really puzzles me is this: If I set `se=FALSE`, so that no standard errors are computed, it works:

```
out <-  gsynth(corruption ~ eu + democracy + bnp, data = vdem5, 
                      index = c("country","year"), force = "two-way",
                      CV = TRUE, r= c(0,5), se = FALSE, 
                      inference = "parametric", nboots = 1000,
                      parallel = FALSE)
```

Now it runs through just fine:

[image]

This seems to indicate that that `data` is in fact not `NULL` at the time of running, unless the error message refers to some ther variable with the same name under the hood, maybe?

I would really love to get ahold of those standard errors. Anyone have any tips or similar experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem myself by adding more units (aka countries), though the exact reason it failed before is still not clear to me. I've posted an [issue](https://github.com/xuyiqing/gsynth/issues/56) on the gsynth github page, recommend anyone struggling with this later on to check it out.

UPDATE:

It turned out that the cause of the problem was the CRAN version of gsynth, removing this and installing vis devtools:

`devtools::install_github('xuyiqing/gsynth')`

solved the issue!